# How to remove the prefix to response element in web services

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, webservice-client

I am facing one weird issue in web services. Functionality is working fine,but the response have some unneccessary namespace to the response element, That prefix is not at all defined in the wsdl or stubs. How to remove the unneccessary prefixes in the response element, that namespace is not at all defined in the WSDL. Please help me out to resolve.

Output:

```
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <p30:realTimeWSProviderResponse xmlns:p30="http://eh.actimize.com">
         <requestId/>
         <searchDefinitionId/>
         <generateAlert/>
```

Expected Output:

```
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RealTimeWSProviderResponse xmlns="http://eh.actimize.com">
     <requestId xmlns=""/>
     <searchDefinitionId xmlns=""/>
     <generateAlert xmlns=""/>
     <enableSuppression xmlns=""/>
     <partyType xmlns=""/>
     <partyKey xmlns=""/>
     <names xmlns="">
```

Comment: What is the namespace of `requestId` supposed to be?

Comment: I have updated in the question:  It should be <requestId xmlns=""/>,